# Using existing data sets withing Azure data factory in a new data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm having trouble using existing data sets withing Azure data factory when I want to create a new data flow. under data set combo box in data factory doesn't load the existing data sets.
Also when I want to create a new data set most of the data sources such as SQL server is disable.

Is there any idea?

please see this screen shot

[I Can not select the data sets which was built before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAs53.png)
When I press new data set sql server is disable and I can not select it.

[SQL server in this list is disabled and can not be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmoRC.png)

Comment: Could you please provide some meaningful example of what you are describing such as a block of code, an image or anything to get more detail on what your issue  or question is.

Answer (score 0):

Data flow supports seven type source by now, SQL server is not supported. If your exist dataset isn't within these types, you can't choose them. More Details please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source).

[image]

Comment: My DatawareHouse is on VM Azure but some databases are on premises, So How Can I make  transformations to DatawareHouse?

Comment: for example how can I make dimension , when I can't use data  flow?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use SQL Server within a Data Flow, prior to the Data Flow you need to run a Copy activity to stage your data from SQL Server into a location reachable by the subsequent Data Flow.  The easiest option to use is a Delimited text file (CSV) in Azure Blob Storage.